# Writing variables of different types to binary file and then reading them into class variables gives wrong values

Tags: c++, fwrite, fread

I am trying to create to read from a binary file into variables of a class. The integers are read and displayed correctly but the double gets a weird value. I'm not sure what is happening here. The output of the command windows is:

```
98
366
7
-9.25596e+61
```

Here's my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

class text
{
private:
    int var1, var2, var3;
    double var4;
public:
    int getVar1() { return var1; }
    int getVar2() { return var2; }
    int getVar3() { return var3; }
    double getVar4() { return var4; }
};

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Create test binary file
    FILE* file = fopen("D:\\Desktop\\TestFile", "wb");

    // Define test variables
    int var1 = 98, var2 = 366, var3 = 7;
    double var4 = 52.13;

    // Write test variables to file
    fwrite(&var1, sizeof(var1), 1, file);
    fwrite(&var2, sizeof(var2), 1, file);
    fwrite(&var3, sizeof(var3), 1, file);
    fwrite(&var4, sizeof(var4), 1, file);

    fclose(file);

    // Read from file into class
    FILE* input;
    input = fopen("D:\\Desktop\\TestFile", "rb");
    text t;
    fread(&t, sizeof(t), 1, input);

    cout << t.getVar1() << endl << t.getVar2() << endl << t.getVar3() << endl << t.getVar4() << endl;

    fclose(input);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try reading into the variables of `text` directly. the size of `t` is not necessarily the same as the summation of the sizes of all its member variables.

Comment: The members of the `text` class may have padding between them. When you write the individual members, you're not writing the padding, so when you try to read into the whole class, you don't skip over the padding bytes.

Comment: you are not reading the same as what you wrote in the file. You write 3 ints and a double but you try to read a `text` object. Try to make writing & reading symmetric

Comment: So either write and read the whole class, or write and read each member separately. You have to be consistent.

Comment: Also, just to warn you, if you change the `text` class in any way so that it is no longer a POD type, the entire idea of reading and writing the type to a binary file like that will not work.  Right now [you're safe](http://ideone.com/Vwgs97), but if `std::is_pod<text>()` ever returns 0, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is allowed to pad your `struct`, and it does in this case:

Here's a test to print out the size of 3 ints + the size of 1 double versus the size of an instance of `text` ([demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8533501fbe23a1f5)):

```
class text
{
private:
 int var1, var2, var3;
 double var4;
public:
 int getVar1() { return var1; }
 int getVar2() { return var2; }
 int getVar3() { return var3; }
 double getVar4() { return var4; }
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << sizeof(int) + sizeof(int) + sizeof(int) + sizeof(double) << " versus " << sizeof(text) << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

> 20 versus 24

This happens because the compiler likes to align things (and is free to do so unless you specify otherwise).

Instead, I suggest you overload the `>>` operator for `text`, use `std::ifstream`, and `std::ofstream` because you're using C++, and read into the members directly.

Comment: imho this one of the first things everybody should learn about c++. It was one of my eye openers when I realized how easy it actually is to read/write objects to a file with overloaded in/output operators (after years of diletantish fooling around with c i/o in c++)